# Could not load file or assembly error on GetTypes method

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I am reading dlls and process types from a folder.

```
xxx.dll
xxx.interfaces.dll
```

When I load xxx.dll and call GetTypes on that assembly, it is throwing an exception...

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'xxx.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = xxx
LOG: DisplayName = xxx.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///<myapp>/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: <myapp>\bin\Debug\Diagrammer.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
}
```

It seems it is trying to fetch the dependent dll from the launching application path than the assembly being loaded. When I check loading and processing the assembly xxx.Interfaces.dll, it worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried both `Assembly.Load` and `Assembly.LoadFrom`?

Comment: I was using LoadFile api. Thanks for your reference, LoadFrom is working.

Comment: You should give it as answer. It might be helpful to someone else who is in my situation. I will try to give my observations on top of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using either [Assembly.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.assembly.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Assembly.LoadFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `LoadFrom()` should not complain about dependencies which is probably caused by this fact

> The load-from context allows an assembly to be loaded from a path not included in probing, and yet allows dependencies on that path to be found and loaded because the path information is maintained by the context.

Sample code

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
var availableTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
```

Comment: Why `LoadFrom` doesn't complains about dependencies? how does it work?

Comment: Edited my answer based on reading on MSDN. Hope that will please you.

Comment: You saved my working day, thanks! I loaded assemblies with Assembly.LoadFile() leading into the exception described by the OP.

Comment: Head banging this one to, not completely sure on difference between the two calls, but simply changing to the LoadFrom got my code moving again.

Comment: This was essential in converting our .NET 4.8 solution to .NET 6, thank you